# jQuery window resize doesn't work on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, orientation, freeze

The site I'm working on is freezing on orientation change, which falls under the resize function. After a lot of rewriting, it would work with the resize event moved outside of the plug in. This resulted in other unwanted behavior, so it's not ideal.

Any idea why it's getting stuck? Other plugins I know of, such as Supersized, run through doc ready, load, and resize in a similar way without the hang up.. So I know there's probably some little detail about how I wrote it that's causing it.

Thaks for your help!

Test site:
http://brantley.dhut.ch/

JavaScript:

Plug in-

```
(function( $ ){
    $.fn.respond = function(callback) {

        /* initialize function on window load and resize */
        $(document).ready(function() {
            dimensions();
        });
        $(window).resize(function() {
            dimensions();
        });

        /* declare affected elements */
        var pic = this

        /* set image's height or width depending on the browser window's size */
        function dimensions() {
            return pic.each(function() {

            /* declare variables */
                var browserWidth = $(window).width();
                var imgRatio = $(this).width() / $(this).height()
                var availableHeight = ($(window).height() - $('header').height() - $('footer').height() - 80)
                var browserRatio = browserWidth / availableHeight

                /* image sizing logic */
                if (browserRatio >= imgRatio) {
                    if (browserWidth > 640) {
                        /* if the browser is landscape and bigger than mobile, set the image's height to fill the available space */
                        $(this).height(availableHeight).width('auto');
                        //$('body').css('background', 'blue');
                    } else {
                        /* it's mobile */
                        $(this).width(browserWidth - 40).height('auto');
                        //$('body').css('background', 'red');
                    }
                } else {
                    /* if the browser is portrait, set the image's width to fill the page */
                    $(this).width(browserWidth - 40).height('auto');
                    //$('body').css('background', 'green');
                }

                /* horizontally center content */
                $(this).css('margin-left', (browserWidth - $(this).width())/2);

            });

        };
        callback();     
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Execution-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /* run respond and hide the main images */
    $('.z').respond(function() {
        $('.z').hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: Are you viewing the site through Safari? What version of iOS, or is it all of them?

Comment: Viewing the site on my iPad 2 running 4.3.5. Running into the same issue on Apple's iOS simulator.